# How to add an active class on specific “li” on user click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've scoured the web for a straightforward answer and I have not been able to find it. Spent too long trying to figure this out, but I'd appreciate any help or the right direction.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="main-li">
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item1</li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById('main-li').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === "LI") {
    e.target.classList.add("active-class");
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/kw0rr3fv/1/

According to David Wash: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

> Event delegation allows you to avoid adding event listeners to
>   specific nodes;  instead, the event listener is added to one parent. 
>   That event listener analyzes bubbled events to find a match on child
>   elements

What is the best way to remove the previous active-class while attaching the class to the selected element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that exists to remove a class to each child of the UL, is to iterate over them.

If you wish to avoid frameworks like jQuery, you can simply achieve it with a very short code:

```
document.getElementById('main-li').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === "LI") {
        let elements = document.getElementById('main-li').children;
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
            elements[i].classList.remove("active-class");
        }
        e.target.classList.add("active-class");
     }
}, true);
```

As you see I just added a very short loop to your code that removes the class (it won't block in case the element doesn't have the class).

In the last line of code you may notice I have added a `true` value: this is the *use capture* and is used to suggest that UL event must be captured by LI childrens.

Comment: I really like your solution. It's clean and does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> I found this to be more challenging than I expected. Is this a common
>   way to set an active class?

You can use a framework like jQuery which will help you do it faster and in cross-browser fashion.

> What is the best way to remove the previous active-class while
>   attaching it to the selected element?

Check the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kw0rr3fv/4/)

```
document.getElementById('main-li').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#main-li li')).forEach( function( obj ){
    obj.classList.remove("active-class");
  });
  if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === "LI") {
    e.target.classList.add("active-class");
  }
});
```

You need to remove the class from all li's first and then go ahead with adding the `active-class`

Answer (score 1):

I think should be focus only tag "li" and add event listener as my simple code and easy to read below.

```
var elementsLi = document.querySelectorAll('ul#main-li > li');

for (var i = 0; i < elementsLi.length; i++) {
    elementsLi[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
         // console.log(e.currentTarget); // for see the current element
         if (e.currentTarget.classList.contains('active-class')) {
              // do something if already have class "active-class"
              // remove class or blah blah blah
         }
         else {
              e.currentTarget.classList.add('active-class')
         }
    });
}
```

Hope your success :)

Comment: When you need to remove all "active-class" you can add logic to remove class from all "li" before add "active-class" at current element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Jquery for this. which is fast and shorter than your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#main-li').on('click',function(){
$(this).addClass('active-class').siblings().removeClass('active-class');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Created page which add class "active" on every "li" element click.

```html
<style>
 .active { color: red; }
</style>

<ul>
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item2</li>
     <li>item3</li>
</ul>

<script>
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
 arr[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
 
   for(var j=0; j<document.getElementsByTagName("li").length; j++){
    document.getElementsByTagName("li")[j].className = "";
    event.target.className = "";
   };
 
  event.target.className = "active"
 });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please read the Question requirements. You're missing to de-select the previous items

Comment: Added de-selecting :)